# Unable to receive events in SOCKET.IO client

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am new to socket.io and i am trying out the examples mentioned on their site. I am going good with it but problem occurs when i try to use io.emit on the server side and try to receive on client side.

Here is my server code

```
var io=require("socket.io").listen(8888);
io.set('log level',1);
io.on('connection',function(socket){ 
socket.emit('hi');
console.log("Connected");
});
```

And my client's code

```
<script src="http://localhost:8888/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket=io.connect("http://localhost:8888");
socket.set('log_level',1);
socket.on('hi',function(){
console.log('received');
});
</script>
```

The problem is i don't see the message 'received' in the console! The answer may be trivial but i tried experimenting but failed everytime. Please guide....

I am on ubuntu firefox. node version: 0.8.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you should have this on the serve side:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(88888);
io.set('log level',1);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('hi);
  console.log("Connected");
  });
});
```

And you should have this on the client side:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8888/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8888/');
  socket.set('log_level',1);
  socket.on('hi', function () {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

WebSockets like many html5 features does not work in a non webserver environment. I mean It won't work if you are accessing your client with the file protocol.
You need to have a http server.
What I do to get things done easily, I use python built-in web-server. It does the job.
Just spawn it in you client folder like this:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

And then point your browser to port 8000 (default).

I've made a [boiler plate](https://github.com/dotcloud/socket.io-on-dotcloud) socket.io app that you can clone and even push directly to [dotCloud.com](http://dotcloud.com)
This is a simple example and could help you to get started with socket.io.

Comment: @MrinalPurohit I may have found the solution to your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Look for examples on the [soket.io GitHub page](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io).

You wrote: `io.on('connection'` instead `io.sockets.on('connection'`

This code should work fine:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8888);
io.set('log level', 1);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){ 
    socket.emit('hi');
    console.log("Connected");
});
```

Comment: well no, i don't see a difference by making the change you mentioned....i just get 'connected'. It should show 'received' well....

Comment: I just checked this code. It works fine for me. Chrome 21, node.js 0.8.7, socket.io 0.9.9

Comment: well thats what surprises me....can there be other factors for not being able to sent the custom events from server? something related to environment....???

Comment: Maybe there's problem with WebSocket, you can try other browser without WS (IE, Opera) or Safari on Windows... they work fine for me. Or try to force socket.io use long polling. WS is known not work on some environment (firewall, av...)

Comment: I have two different applications with socket.io on production withiout any problems. Tested in IE, Opera, Safari, Chrome, FF on Windows, and Chrome, FF, Opera on Linux Ubuntu. Opera and IE uses xhr-pooling, Crome, FF and Safari uses websocket. Tested on default environment (windows 7 firewall enabled). Recently we had some problems with websocket on machines with Avast antivirus.